# how to get desired order by expansion in bash

Tags: bash

```
$ echo  {A,B}{1,2,3}.pdf
A1.pdf A2.pdf A3.pdf B1.pdf B2.pdf B3.pdf
```

How can I get the following output:

```
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf
```

Thanks.

Comment: With all the [usual caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), `ls [AB][123].pdf | sort -V`

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this is cheating, but it does give the desired output:

```
echo fdp.{3,2,1}{B,A} | rev
```

Comment: That's not cheating. That's clever!

Answer (score 3):

The result of brace expansion is *not sorted* and **left to right order** is preserved.

To achieve your desired output you can do the following but you can see how quickly it can get complicated.

```
$ echo {{A,B}1,{A,B}2,{A,B}3}.pdf
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf
```

Simple `loop` should be easy to scale and read:

```
$ for n in {1..3}; do list+=( {A..B}$n.pdf ); done; echo "${list[@]}"
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf
```

I have used an intermediate array to store expanded names. You may choose to print them as your encounter. I am assuming your intention is to do something with them once they are generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in 1 2 3; do for l in A B; do echo -n "$l$n.pdf "; done; done; echo

or

for n in {1..3}; do for l in {A..B}; do echo -n "$l$n.pdf "; done; done; echo
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is the loop range `1 2 3` a list? can we write it more  clearly/explicitly so that it is a list? (2) can my question be done without loop?

Comment: @Tim How would you "write it more clearly/explicitly" as a list? Do you mean brace expansion?

Comment: @Tim: 1 2 3 are treated as strings. You could use $(seq 1 3) to get a programmable sequence. There are commands that will map ascii to get the same effect from A B C, with all the caveats that apply there. I don't think you can do it without a loop. The doc for bash says that the left-to-right order is preserved in brace expansion.

Comment: brace expansion can do letters too. `echo {A..C}` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for n in 1 2 3; do printf '%s ' {A,B}"$n.pdf"; done; echo
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf

$ for n in 1 2 3; do echo -n {A,B}"$n.pdf "; done; echo
A1.pdf  B1.pdf A2.pdf  B2.pdf A3.pdf  B3.pdf

$ for n in 1 2 3; do echo -n {A,B}"$n.pdf"; echo -n " "; done; echo
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf

# One of the relatively rare times where not quoting a command substitution is useful.
$ echo $(printf %s\\n {A,B}{1,2,3}.pdf | sort -k1.2,1.2)
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf

# Same idea as above but with different all-on-one line mechanism.
$ printf %s\\n {A,B}{1,2,3}.pdf | sort -k1.2,1.2 | tr '\n' ' '; echo
A1.pdf B1.pdf A2.pdf B2.pdf A3.pdf B3.pdf
```